# What Is Wrong With My fail2ban regex?

Tags: regex, fail2ban

My fail2ban exim filter has been working fine up until a few days ago. I haven't made any changes to the filter, and the lines in my exim log look identical to what they used to look like. However fail2ban is failing to auto-ban these multiple attempts.

I've been using the following regex, and fail2ban has been working fine:

```
^%(pid)s \w+ authenticator failed for (\S+ )?\(\S+\) \[<HOST>\]: 535 Incorrect authentication data( \(set_id=.*\)|: \d+ Time\(s\))?\s*$
```

When I noticed that wasn't working, I tweaked it a bit to this yesterday:

```
^%(pid)s (plain|login) authenticator failed for (\S+ )?\(\S+\) \[<HOST>\]: 535 Incorrect authentication data( \(set_id=.*\)|: \d+ Time\(s\))?\s*$
```

But that didn't seem to want to work either. My log format looks like this:

```
2015-06-30 11:37:31 login authenticator failed for (User) [194.63.140.62]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=general@mail.net)
2015-06-30 11:45:30 login authenticator failed for (User) [194.63.140.62]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=guest@mail.net)
2015-06-30 11:53:34 login authenticator failed for (User) [194.63.140.62]: 535 Incorrect authentication data (set_id=sample@mail.net)
```

Does anyone see anything wrong with my regex specifications?